# According to Eastern Orthodoxy why did we inherit the sin of Adam and Eve?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, adam-and-eve, original-sin, justice

God is known as very just and he likes to have mercy on people.

God doesn't want people to inherit sins of their parents. So why did we inherit this very sin? What is so special about the sin of Adam and Eve?

I feel like that it's against justice because we didn't make it. It's also against having mercy because we inherited a sin which leads to death.

Comment: related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/57874/if-baptism-cleanses-original-sin-then-why-do-the-children-of-baptised-parents-st

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sin is a damage we do to ourselves. Adam and Eve damaged themselves and we inherited this sin, like child inherits damage if his mother smokes or drinks alcohol during pregnancy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. By saying an "Earthly" example, I think you mean we just inherited the "Earthly" damage but the "Heavenly" or the "Spiritual" damage is lifted by Jesus' crucifixion and by the daily repentance and forgiveness. For me, it makes sense now and it's not against justice nor mercy.

Comment: Pretty close to what I would have said, Arrowd. When they sinned, it corrupted both of them, and the corruption has been passed down by man ever since.